# Identity for $1/z$, $\cot(z)$, and $\coth(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to verify a seemingly simple identity that I encountered in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.07269). After discarding some irrelevant scale factors it boils down to the following. It comes in three variants,

$$
\alpha(z) =
\begin{cases}
1/z & \text{(I),} \\
\cot(z) & \text{(II),} \\
\coth(z) & \text{(III),}
\end{cases}
$$

and says that

$$\alpha(a-b)\alpha(b-c) + \alpha(b-c)\alpha(c-a) + \alpha(c-a)\alpha(a-b) = C,$$

for $a,b,c \in \mathbb C$, where

$$
C =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{(I),} \\
1 & \text{(II),} \\
-1 & \text{(III).}
\end{cases}
$$

Case (I) is straightforward to verify, but I am having trouble with cases (II) and (III). I have tried to use various trigonometric identities to make progress, but have not managed to get it all the way. I'm sure it's simple, and I'm just missing some key step. Any advice?

Comment: Just an idea: fix $b$ and $c$ and take the (holomorphic) derivative with respect to $a$ of the LHS. It should be $0$, and since the domain of definition will be connected, the LHS should be constant. Find some initial data to conclude

Comment: @Didier I had the same idea, but did not manage to reduce the expression to zero. Maybe I should try that again, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All choices of $\alpha$ are odd. In terms of $x:=a-b,\,y:=b-c$, (II) states$$\cot x\cot y-(\cot x+\cot y)\cot(x+y)=1,$$which is trivial. Similarly with (III).

Comment: Ah, I see. Seems obvious now! Thank you!